# Inputing Value in sql after counting c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm kind of new to this but I'll try to give as much detail as possible.  This is my SQL table.

`Customers`

`Customers_Id (PK) | First | Last  |    Address   |   Phone  | Tech_Id (FK) |
-------------------+-------+-------+--------------+----------+--------------+
        1          |  Bob  | Smith | 123 Fake St. | 3298492  |  1           |
        2          |  John | Man   | 123 Noe St.  | 2930482  |  1           |
        3          |  Tom  | Lee   | 123 Polk St. | 9308523  |  2           |
 ...`

`Tech`

`Tech_Id (PK) | First | Last  | Phone   | Customer_Count |
--------------+-------+-------+---------+----------------+
        1     |  Tim  | Bo    | 9384027 |                |
        2     |  Andy | Wong  | 9374927 |                |
        3     |  Jack | Help  | 2183847 |                |
 ...`

I'm trying to find the best way to count how many customer that each tech has either using SQL Query or C# coding.  I was thinking of doing query with Count and then insert into the Customer_Count in Tech table.

I'm using visual studio 2012 and SQL is created locally in visual studio.  Please help!

Comment: The reason for the customer count is because I need to calculate the average customer each tech should have and then when there's new customer, it will assign that customer to the tech that's below that average.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I prefre to using Sql ,but failed...Disappionted..
But I am sure that you can use Ado.net to do this job.
Here is C# demo code.

```
        //query from db use C#
        var allCus = new List<Customers>();
        var gps = allCus.GroupBy(w => w.Tech_Id);
        foreach(var gp in gps) {
            var techId = gp.Key;
            var cnt = gp.Count();
            //update Tech set Customer_Count = cnt where Tech_Id = techId
        }
```

---

Here is Sql version

```
update Tech set Customer_Count = (select IdAndCnt.cnt from (select Tech_Id,count (Tech_id) as cnt from Customers group by Tech_Id ) as IdAndCnt where Tech.Tech_Id = IdAndCnt.Tech_Id)
```

Holp it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through SQL - using a `GROUP BY` clause to group the result by each tech. You can use the `COUNT` function to return the number of customers assigned to each tech. You can put this in an `UPDATE` statement to update the customer_count field in the tech table for each tech.

For example:

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.customer_count = COUNT(c.customer_id)
FROM tech t 
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.tech_id = t.tech_id
GROUP BY c.tech_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Customer_Count column from the tech table. It's best not to make columns which duplicate available data unless there's a valid performance reason. If you want it displayed as such, then create a view:

```
SELECT t.tech_id, 
       t.first, 
       t.last, 
       t.phone, 
       (SELECT COUNT(c.customer_id) 
        FROM customers c
        WHERE c.tech_id = t.tech_id) AS Customer_Count
FROM tech t
```

Now you can query it like a table, but you're not tasked with maintaining data which is always up to date through this view.

Comment: So if I want to put this in C# and find which tech have the lowest amount of customer, how do I do that?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <viewName> ORDER BY Customer_Count ASC` is your query, so you could process the data from there. There are countless ways to get the data in C#, and they are well documented and easily searchable.